# Porting Visual C/C++ to Android

Tags: android, visual-c++, android-ndk, porting

In my recently started internship (I'm studying computer science), I have to port a somewhat big existing Project to Android. It is a Visual C/C++ Project which in the end should run on Android using of course the NDK. The problem is that I don't know a thing about porting software, since this is not covered in my studies...

I had a few days to get to know the project I will be working with a little.

A few words about the complexity:
It is a Visual Studio solution which consists of 28 projects of which most are kind of big...

And now I need to develop a concept for porting it to Android, and this is why I'm writing this. I have absolutely no idea know where to start, also I don't know how to get to a concept for porting it. I tried searching online for some stuff or for some books covering this, but I found nothing.

Of course I know, that basically I have to remove everything that is Visual/Windows specific and replace it with appropriate Android/Linux functions or implement something new if there is nothing corresponding on Android.

But since this project is somewhat huge, I can't just try to compile it with the correct compiler and work through the error messages, this will lead to nowhere, I guess...

So now my actual question:
Is anybody experienced about this or something similar and can give some tips how to start with it? As I said, I first need a concept. Something more general about how to start and deal with porting a software project of this size is also very welcome, since I don't know nothing about it...

Comment: Others are assuming `.net`. I assumed not. Is it `.net`?

Comment: no its not .net, its just c++ using quite a lot of Visual specific stuff and some Windows specific Stuff like handles...

Comment: oh, and logically (for the sort of programm) it must use a database, but i have not seen it in the code yet (as written the project is quite huge...), but i think they want me to use the SQLite Database of Android in the portet Version...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're approaching the whole matter in the wrong way. There are several tools that will allow you to compile C# and visual C++ and other visual languages from their respected IDEs to the android platform. For example there is [mono for android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) . Mono is a plugin for visual studio which helps you create android projects using visual studio and .net technologies. I think you should focus your research on tools like this because changing all of the code manually is nearly impossible and too time consuming. [Here](http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/15/Android-applications-in-C-using-Visual-Studio.aspx) is a page that will help you get started with mono for android. Good luck.

Comment: I doubt that this is a decent solution, you are trading the C/C++ for an abstract framework that will make you loose performance; this kind of frameworks are for people that have a particular know-how and want to make small apps or apps without too much optimization. Your answer is 50%/50%

Comment: I will agree with you but it all depends on the available timeframe. If you have to deploy a project ASAP then an automated solution is better for starters. The next versions could be rewritten in native android code if there is the luxury of time. We've faced the same issue in my company so we used a third party IDE for the first version while the next one was rewritten from scratch in java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks interesting, but i'm afraid that the company where im doin my internship dont want to buy new software just for me. But I will propose it, since they're just starting with andoid development, they may need a good solution...

Comment: And just another question, since you were talking about the available time. I have about 20 Weeks from now till my internships ends, 20 for envolving a concept and implement. It is definitly not a solution to rewrite it in java, but is it better to rewrite the in Android unsupportet parts of manually or doesnt that just make no difference to using something like mono? Oh, and i guess also when using mono for Android some parts need to be rewritten? Windows specific stuff also wont work with mono i guess? But "normal" Visual specific stuff is translated with mono or am i getting this wrong?

Comment: another question i stumbled upon by reading some stuff about mono for android is, do mono even support Visual C++? They always talk about Visual C#, but i found no example/article about using Visual C++ with mono for android... sry, for this mass of comments, i would be really glad if you have some answers for all this stuff... :)

Comment: After my first day of explicit research for my concept for porting, it looks like not using an automated solution but working trough the code and step by step removing everything Visual an Windows specific and replace it with under android available stuff to get it to run on android this way... But im still very interested in answers to my questions in the comments above, so i will maybe change my mind.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [Android NDK with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056606/android-ndk-with-visual-studio).
Personally I don't use this, but It seems to be a nice solution to your problem.
Like you, in the past, we had to port a big Visual C++ library project to Android, we proceeded in this way:

1. Try to compile the main library interface (by creating the relative Android.mk)
2. By using linking errors, you should guess other projects to be compiled and create the mks for them
3. Cycle until you have no more linking errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was just the first thing that come to my mind, but i guess the Project is really way to big for it, and also contains a lot of Visual Stuff which wont compile for android, so i guess brachiating trough the errors would be some kind of neverending story...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell about the source code size of the project (how many thousands of lines of source code).

If the code size is big enough (e.g. at least 100 [KLOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code)), you could consider customizing the GCC compiler (assuming a recent 4.6 or 4.7 version), perhaps using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high level domain specific language to extend GCC), or painfully coding in *C* a GCC plugin. This GCC customizing approach is worthwhile only for large code bases (you'll need several days to master GCC internals).

On the other hand, many well designed applications may have packaged their operating system functions inside a well defined interface and library. You might consider porting your application to Qt or some other cross-platform library.

We need more details about your project to help you more.

Comment: The thing about more details is that i had a few Days to understand the Project roughly and now i should evolve a concept for porting it to android, so i myself am do not know to much about the details of the Project. But i think custiomizing the gcc compiler is an overkill, since this is my work for an internship and as far as i know they are quite optimistic that i can do it... maybe i leave another comment if my concept is taking form and i do know more stuff about the Project

Comment: You could tell what kind of application is it, and what is is approximate source code size.