# Porting Visual C/C++ to Android, stopover at linux?

Tags: android, linux, visual-c++, android-ndk, porting

I need to port a fairly large Visual C/C++ Project to Android in my recently started internship.
I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034132/porting-visual-c-c-to-android) about that topic yesterday, asking for some help finding a concept for the porting.
I got an answer suggesting an automated solution (sth like mono for android), but after a day of research explicit for my concept, i tend to a "manual solution", which shall mean that i manually remove everythin Windos- and Visual specific by hand and replace it with unter Android available Functions.

Now, the first thing that comes to my mind is to first remove everything Visual specific by using the windows gnu Complier, and after that removing everything Windows sprecific by using the linux gnu Compiler (and than make it runnable on Android using the ndk).

This implicates that i port it from Windows to Linux and than from Linux to Android, assuming that the Linux to Android step is a quite small one since i hope that the Code can remain nearly unmodified from Linux to Android because Android is based on the Linux Kernel.

Now my question is: Is this a good idea, or is porting from Linux to Android also an great effort, so that i would do all work twice, once from Windows to Linux and than another time from Linux to Android?!

Suggestions how to do it better are absolutly welcome!

EDIT: Forget to mention, this will be part of an larger Application and does not contain any GUI Stuff (of cource i know in that cause although the linux to Android Step would be heavy work), just Interfaces to the components lying above and below.

Comment: Instead of just removing or replacing the Windows specific parts, try instead to more abstract interfaces or wrappers that can call the correct Windows, Linux or Android code depending on environment it's built in. It might be more work in the beginning, but then will be easier to port in the future.

Comment: @nurgan, can you please provide us with your contact info, we need to have your advice please as we have a similar project to port for android .. thanks

Comment: i actually do not know how this project ended, since i cancelled my internship in this company due to the <Irony>'massive ammount of support'</Irony> i got...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manually remove the "Windows stuff".

Instead create an "emulation layer" - define all windows functions used by your project in a header and write their bodies.

Thus you'll keep your project untouched and even take it's new versions if any.

When porting Windows->Linux you might encounter the following "big" issues:

- windows registry emulation
- windows multi-threading model and IPC is a bit difficult to translate into Linux terms. Especially the SetEvent and WaitForMultipleObjects
- GUI (but I understand, you haven't any)

The biggest trouble in porting Linux->Android should be the UI. If you have no user-interaction involved, I *would* recommend to port win->lin first.

You could bring and build missing libraries from Linux if needed.

If any user interaction is needed, you might want to write native Android front-end app in Java and interact with your main program by D-Bus.

Comment: You're definitly right, an "emulation layer" is Way better than doin some ugly editing of the running and tested Code, but my Question can also refer to this. Is it better to first do the "emulation Layer" for Linux where i guess it is more easy to (try to) compile it and debug it, and afterwards make the "emaulation layer" for andorid with little changes, or am i doing the work twice - because the changes in the "emulation layer" arent that small as i assume - in this case?

Comment: Ok, that depends on the level of interaction of your application with OS. Try to enumerate the main fields of such interactions and I will add the probable impact description to the answer.

Comment: well, there is Multithreading (not to much), and really a lot of handles (they are windowsspecific arent they? im not too deep into c/c++ programming...) everywhere...

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. And relived me, that my first guess to first port it to linux and than its just a small step to android was right (still excluding gui), my view of the world would have collapsed if that would have been wrong i guess... :)

Comment: You have a lot of work yet. I've done such a porting in the past, and while the first alfa came up after a month with untouched logics and windows emulation, for the final release I've rewritten the multithreading logics and the IPC...

Comment: @LiMar would you work as a freelancer to port a project for us? how can we communicate please?

Comment: @simo No, I couldn't. Totally dedicated to a full-time job. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, can you recommend someone knowledgable? or at least, the recommended approach? thanks